# Не отправляется файл ajax запросом

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Очень странная ситуация. Когда запускаю проект в студии, выбираю файл в форме он отправляется и возвращает нужные мне данные. После публикации на сервере данный метод не работает

код контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PersProc()
{
    HttpPostedFileBase persProc = Request.Files[0];
    //чтение файла и преобразование в текст
    BinaryReader reader_persProc = new BinaryReader(persProc.InputStream);
    byte[] binData = reader_persProc.ReadBytes(persProc.ContentLength);
    string strData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binData);

    var context = new NewSkladTestEntities();
    var data = context.procTo1C_CheckPerc(strData).ToList();

    return Json(new { success = true, data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/XmlFor1CAuthWin/Home/PersProc/',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

            success: function (data) {
                var output = "<table><tr><th>№</th><th>ФИО</th> <th>%</th></tr>";
                for (var i in data.data) {
                    output += "<tr>" + "<td>" + data.data[i].TabNum + "</td>";
                    output += "<td>" + data.data[i].FIO + "</td>";
                    output += "<td>" + data.data[i].perc + "</td>" + "</tr>";

                }
                output += "</table>";

                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = output;

                jQuery("#myDialogText").html(output);
                $(function () {
                    $("#myDialogText").dialog({
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        width: 400,
                        height: 500
                    });
                });
            },

            error: function (error) {
                error();
            }
        })
```

ошибку пишет следующую:

```
jquery-1.12.4.js:10254 POST http://192.168.2.52/XmlFor1CAuthWin/Home/PersProc 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Наиболее частой причиной ошибки 500 (Internal Server Error, внутренняя ошибка сервера) является неверный синтаксис файла .htaccess или наличие в нем неподдерживаемых директив. Чаще всего достаточно закомментировать директиву Options (для этого нужно поставить в начале строки решетку — #), и проблема исчезнет.

Comment: @And файла  .htaccess нет. Вместо него скорее всего служит web.config. Но что там поменять не знаю.

Comment: Файл один и тот же пробуете отправлять?

Comment: @Jagailo Да, один и тот же. Сейчас чуть подправил и catch возвращает `Method not found Void System.Data.ObjectContextOptions.set_UseConsistentNullReferenceBehavior(Boolean`

Comment: решило проблему пересоздание приложения.